docker - qbittorent - The bound address is already in use
Recently I deployed arr-stack (via portainer) running behind gluetun vpn. Everything works fine but until I need to either restart (or re-deploy) the stack or qBittorent container. Then qBittorent is not available due to error shown in logs:
[custom-init] No custom files found, skipping...
WebUI will be started shortly after internal preparations. Please wait...
"WebUI: Unable to bind to IP: 192.168.16.2, port: 8085. Reason: The bound address is already in use"
Unable to bind to IP: 192.168.16.2, port: 8085. Reason: The bound address is already in use
******** Information ********
To fix the error, you may need to edit the config file manually.
Connection to 192.168.16.2 8085 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
[ls.io-init] done.

The error text  is a bit misleading, "The bound address is already in use" actually means the port. The port is the same I used when deploying the stack (docker compose is at bottom). I did not deploy any other container to use the same port. I faced this issue many times and tried multiple things.

stopped and removed the stack
removed unused volumes
checked if there is any other container using the port before docker restart, all I saw was:

sudo lsof -i :8085
COMMAND       PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 3544820 root    4u  IPv4 44522160      0t0  TCP *:8085 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 3544826 root    4u  IPv6 44522591      0t0  TCP *:8085 (LISTEN)

Not really sure what those are but I killed those and then completely restarted docker. After docker started again and before deploying the stack with the same port for qBittorent I also checked whether port was already taken:
sudo netstat -tuln | grep 8085

It did not return any results.
But still I was not able to deploy qBittorent to that port. Then I changed port for qBittorent to 8086 and everything was working again. But the pain is changing all configurations (for all arr apps, homepage etc).
And it only works until next time I need to restart (or redeploy) the stack or just qBittorent. Also happened that qBittorent was automatically stopped and updated by watchtower (automatic docker container updates). The problem was back, now for port 8086. But then if I deploy it with 8085 it works again but I need to change all configs again.
Weird thing is that it only happens for qBittorent no other app.
Here is important part of my docker compose:
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    container_name: gluetun
    hostname: gluetun
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
    networks:
      vpn_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.16.2
    ports:
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
      - 8085:8085 # qbittorrent
      - 9117:9117 # Jackett
      - 8989:8989 # Sonarr
      - 9696:9696 # Prowlarr
      - 7878:7878 # Radarr
      - 8686:8686 # Lidarr
      - 8787:8787 # Readarr
      - 8096:8096 # Jellyfin
      - 5055:5055 # Jellyseerr
      - 3033:3033 # Homepage
      - 8191:8191 # FlareSolverr
      - 8700:8000 # Gluetun HTTP Control Server
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/arr-stack/gluetun:/gluetun
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=surfshark
      - VPN_TYPE=wireguard
      - WIREGUARD_PRIVATE_KEY=<wg-key>
      - WIREGUARD_ADDRESSES=10.14.0.2/16
      - TZ=<timezone>
      - UPDATER_PERIOD=24h
      - HTTP_CONTROL_SERVER=on
    restart: unless-stopped

  qbittorrent:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent
    container_name: qbittorrent
    network_mode: "service:gluetun"
    depends_on:
      - gluetun
    environment:
      - PUID=999
      - PGID=10
      - TZ=<timezone>
      - WEBUI_PORT=8085
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/arr-stack/qbittorrent/config:/config
      - /volume1/docker/arr-stack/data/downloads:/downloads
    restart: always
.
.
.
networks:
  vpn_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.16.0/24"

How to solve this? Why is this happening only for qBittorent?
Thanks!
